# How do I implement an SNMP 'getSubtree' PDU type, and support in an SNMP agent for it?

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I've implemented an SNMP agent using SNMP4J. I've read in various places (including in SNMP4J javadoc) that there is support for a 'getSubtree' operation, but it always seems to be done from the client side, using getNext and/or getBulk. What I'm trying to do, though, is define a new PDU for 'getSubtree', and implement the server-side agent support for it.

Has anyone successfully (a) implemented a new PDU type (beyond the 7 standard ones) using SNMP4J, and/or (b) implemented 'getSubtree' support within an agent (I already know how to simulate it from a client.) Is either (a) or (b) even possible?  Any pointers on how to do either would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNMP is not an extensible protocol that allows you to add new operations to it.  So legally, you can't actually do that.  The RFCs restrict the PDUs to the existing ones.  GETBULK is the most efficient way to gather a bunch of information from an agent, even though it has its own issues with using it (data overrun for example).

Comment: Yes, the data overrun/multiple-requests problem is what I'm trying to deal with. Various pages and papers I've read, however, talk about implementing a 'getSubtree' operation (they do this alongside the standard ones.)  I've seen a proposal (written in the RFC style) for doing it. And I've seen a MIB designed to do it using a SET and multiple traps to respond. While I agree it's only legal to have the standard set of operations, I'm trying to discover/replicate these others. Have you run across this? It's trivial to set up the call from the client, but SNMP4J says it's an invalid type.

Comment: Well, if you control the code on the client and the server then sure, you could add anything you want to both the management stack and the server side agent.  But then you're not doing interoperable SNMP any longer, you're doing something new.  There have been a number of requests to solve this problem, but none of them are standardized.  A few commercial stacks do have extension mechanisms for doing things like that, but again they won't work on every device [in fact, very few].  The best thing you could do is find a rowcount object so you can figure out how to set the GETBULK repeater count

Comment: Thanks, Wes. I did end up (at least for now) going with implementing one version of the client and the server to provide a new PDU on top of SNMP4J. As its signature is very similar to GET, it's pretty straightforward. I agree it's non-standard, but since it's for our own management console it's probably okay. With the size of the data that needs to be sent, it's probably only useful for a TCP connection anyway, which was a common thread I saw in discussions of  getSubtree in various paper.